# dplyr: mutate_at + coalesce: dynamic names of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I've been trying for awhile to combine `mutate_at` with `coalesce` in case in which names of columns are generated dynamically.

In my example there are only five columns, but in the real data there are much more (and not all columns should be included in `coalesce` step).

Example DF:

```
data_example <- data.frame(
  aa = c(1, NA, NA),
  bb = c(NA, NA, 2),
  cc = c(6, 7, 8),
  aa_extra = c(2, 2, NA),
  bb_extra = c(1, 2, 3)
)
```

Expected output:

```
  aa bb cc aa_extra bb_extra
1  1  1  6        2        1
2  2  2  7        2        2
3 NA  2  8       NA        3
```

output as `structure`:

```
structure(list(aa = c(1, 2, NA), bb = c(1, 2, 2), cc = c(6, 7, 
8), aa_extra = c(2, 2, NA), bb_extra = c(1, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I've tried something like this, but without success ("Only strings can be converted to symbols"). I would like to avoid creation of extra variables, just include everything in `mutate_at` expression, since this is a part of longer dplyr "flow".

```
data_example %>%
  dplyr::mutate_at(
    gsub("_extra", "", grep("_extra$",
                            colnames(.),
                            perl = T,
                            value = T)),
    dplyr::funs(
      dplyr::coalesce(., !!! dplyr::sym(paste0(., "_extra")))
    )
  )
```

I've tried also this (no error, but values for column `bb` are wrong):

```
data_example %>%
  dplyr::mutate_at(
    gsub("_extra", "", grep("_extra$",
                            colnames(.),
                            perl = T,
                            value = T)),
    dplyr::funs(
      dplyr::coalesce(., !!as.name(paste0(names(.), "_extra")))
    )
  )
```

How to get the name of processed column and pass it to `coalesce`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can `split` the dataset into a `list` of data.frames after removing the substring of column names (`"_extra"`), then with `map` loop through the `list`, `coalesce` the column and then `bind`with the "_extra" columns in the original dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
data_example %>% 
   split.default(str_remove(names(.), "_extra")) %>%
   map_df(~ coalesce(!!! .x)) %>%
   #or use
   # map_df(reduce, coalesce) %>%
   bind_cols(., select(data_example, ends_with("extra")))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#     aa    bb    cc aa_extra bb_extra
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     1     1     6        2        1
#2     2     2     7        2        2
#3    NA     2     8       NA        3
```

Answer (score 3):

Guess it is now possible to achieve the desired outcome using `mutate + across`

```
data_example %>% 
  mutate(across(c(str_subset(names(.), "_extra") %>% str_remove("_extra")) ,
                ~ coalesce( ., get(str_c(cur_column(), "_extra"))  ))) 

  aa bb cc aa_extra bb_extra
1  1  1  6        2        1
2  2  2  7        2        2
3 NA  2  8       NA        3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` for `melt` and `dcast` since I can never remember how `spread` and `gather` work

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

data_example %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  melt('row') %>% 
  group_by(g = sub('_*$', '', variable), row) %>% 
  mutate(value = reduce(value, coalesce)) %>% 
  dcast(row ~ variable) %>% 
  select(-row)

#   aa bb cc aa_extra bb_extra
# 1  1  1  6        1        1
# 2  2  2  7        2        2
# 3 NA  2  8       NA        2
```